# How to get the intersection of two sets

Tags: google-sheets, worksheet-function

I have two lists (unique sets) in a spreadsheet and I want to get the intersection of the two.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Here's an example of what I want to achieve:

```
List 1  List 2  Expected result

 a       1        e
 b       2        f
 c       e      
 d       4      
 e       f      
 f       6
```

[Example Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AsT3dhEwa6DjdHhZTW9NUHpybGthQXhSdHlxdzVHaEE#gid=0)

Comment: Can you share a doc with us and explain the expected result a bit?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

There is no need to jump into GAS, standard spreadsheet functions handle this easily.

Please paste the following into a cell in [your example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AsT3dhEwa6DjdHhZTW9NUHpybGthQXhSdHlxdzVHaEE#gid=0)

```
=iferror(filter($A$2:$A, match($A$2:$A, B2:$B , false)), "no match")
```

The *match* function generates a cartesian product of the two ranges full of errors except where a match is found.  It returns an index into the 2nd range when a match **is** found.

The *filter* function throws away all the crap and returns only the correctly indexed values.

The *iferror* helps to get a tidy result if there are no matches at all.

The ranges can be of any length, as indicated by the $A$2:$A idiom.

**Update 2021/09/14:**

*Not long ago, I got one of those cowardly drive-by down votes with no explanation.*

However, today I got this edit suggestion:

```
=iferror(filter($A$2:$A; match($A$2:$A; B2:$B; false)); "no match")
```

Has Google deprecated commas, perhaps?

Many thanks to "anonymous_user"!

@rubenrivera.mx no debe rechazar enmiendas que no entiende.

Comment: It is to be noted that it is *not* case sensitive, while the answer from @Daniel, based on query, is case sentitive.

Comment: @thdox Thanx for the clarification.  I'm amazed that my answer is still relevant after 8 years.

Answer (score 4):

This little script will compare two ranges, as a formula:

```
function COMPARE(array1, array2) {
  var array = [];  
  for(i=0; i<array1.length; i++) {
    for(j=0; j<array2.length; j++) {
      if(array1[i][0] == array2[j][0]) {
        // the extra square brackets will make it a 2D array, 
        // aligning it vertically
        array.push([array1[i][0]]);
      }
    }
  }
  return array;
}
```

In your sheet you can add in cell D2 the following formula :

```
=COMPARE(A2:A7,B2:B7)
```

Add the script via the tools menu, script editor.

Comment: I welcome plain old formula's. I could think of them immediately.....

Comment: _could_ should/must be ***couldn't***.......

Comment: Thanks, @Jacob!
I never had a real reason to use formulas in gDocs - thanks for opening me up to this world!

Answer (score 4):

In case you are looking how to find a subtraction of two ranges (elements of range 1 that are not in range 2), like:

```
List 1  List 2  Expected result

 a       1        a
 b       2        b
 c       e        c
 d       4        d
 e       f      
 f       6
```

Here is a formula for you:

```
=iferror(filter($A$2:$A, iserror(match($A$2:$A, B2:$B , false))), "no match")
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a modern answer using Google Sheet [`query` function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343). This is an array function, meaning that it will dynamically generate rows and columns. This precludes the need to add a function per line, you can instead point to the two ranges and get a dynamically sized result.

This is especially helpful if you want to feed this further into another function which needs to operate on the intersection.

If your 2 lists were in column `A` and `B`, then:

##### Case-sensitive soltution:

```
=query(A2:A, "
  select A
  where A matches '"&textjoin("|", true, B2:B)&"'
")
```

##### Case-insensitive solution:

As @thdox noted in the comments, the above answer is case-sensitive. To make a case-insensitive variant, we can use the [Google Query Language `lower` scalar function](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#scalar-functions) as well as the Google Sheet [`lower` function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094083):

```
=query(A2:A, "
  select A
  where lower(A) matches '"&lower(textjoin("|", true, B2:B))&"'
")
```

##### Explanation:

What's happening is that the first column is used as a source, then we filter this source with the [Google Query Language `where` clause's](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#Where) `matches` operator to RegEx match on any of the B column values (turned into a single string with the RegEx OR "|" character via the [`textjoin` function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7013992)).

##### Note:

This method may break if the B list has entries with special regex characters like `\.*[](){}+^$|`.
In this case you would need to escape these special characters with a backslash `\` for this method to work.

Comment: It is to be noted that it is case sensitive, while the answer from @Martin Bramwell, based on filter, is *not* case sentitive.

Comment: Thanks @thdox. Based on your comment I updated my answer and added a case-insensitive version.

Comment: It's good to see these improvements. Very cool!  Thanx.

Answer (score 1):

This little script will compare two ranges, as a formula:

```
function intersect(array1, array2) {
  var array = [];  
  for(i=0; i<array1.length; i++) {
    for(j=0; j<array2.length; j++) {
      if(array1[i][0] == array2[j][0]) {
        // the extra square brackets will make it a 2D array, 
        // aligning it vertically
        array.push([array1[i][0]]);
      }
    }
  }
  return array;
}
```

Extra:

```
function extersect(array1, array2) {
  var array = [];  
  var tmp = true;
  for(i=0; i<array1.length; i++) {
    for(j=0; j<array2.length; j++) {
      if(array1[i][0] == array2[j][0]) {
        // the extra square brackets will make it a 2D array, 
        // aligning it vertically
        tmp = false;
      }      
    }
    if(tmp == true) 
    {
      array.push([array1[i][0]]);
    }
    tmp = true;
  }
  return array;
}
```

In your sheet you can add in cell D2 the following formula :

```
=intersect(A2:A7,B2:B7)
```

Add the script via the tools menu, script editor.

=intersect(A2:A7,B2:B7) returns results that present on both arrays array1, array2.

=extersect(A2:A7,B2:B7) returns values of array1 that does not exists in range B2:B7