# Filtering a range by another range, custom function just says "internal error"

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I'm trying to filter a range by comparing it to another range. I couldn't figure out a way to do this with functions in Google Spreadsheets so I made my own.

```
function FilterByArray(range, filterRange)
{
  var rangeLength = range.length;
  var filterRangeLength = filterRange.length;
  var outputArray = [];

  for(i = 0; i < rangeLength; i++)
  {
    var rangeValue = range[i];
    for(ii = 0; ii < filterRangeLength; i++)
    {
      if(rangeValue == filterRange[ii])
      {
        outputArray.push(rangeValue);
      }
    }
  }
  return outputArray;
}
```

At first glance I thought this would work, and should process in milliseconds with only a couple thousand total iterations. I try and test it and it says `Loading...` for 10-20 seconds then errors out with `Internal Error executing the custom function`.

Why is this, and what can I do to fix it?

Edit: A note, I come from C#, so if there are any glaring issues in this that are unrelated to my question please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to intersect two arrays without a script: see [How to get the intersection of two sets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/40588)

One issue with your code is that all ranges of more than one cells are represented as double arrays for the scripts. E.g., a row  `1 2 3` is `[[1,2,3]]` while a column of the same elements is `[[1],[2],[3]]`. (On the other hand, a single-cell range is just a value.) So you are comparing objects instead of values, which probably isn't going to do what you want, regardless of size.

I use this auxiliary function to flatten double arrays, turning them into single arrays; it also correctly handles one-cell ranges.

```
function flatten(arg) {
  if (arg.constructor === Array) {
    return arg.reduce(function(a, b) { return a.concat(b); });
  }
  else {
    return [arg];
  }
}
```

With that at hand, I'd write something like  this:

```
function FilterByArray(range, filterRange) {
  var flatRange = flatten(range);
  var flatFilter = flatten(filterRange); 
  var outputArray = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < flatRange.length; i++) {
    var value = flatRange[i];
    if (flatFilter.indexOf(value) != -1) {
      outputArray.push(value);
    } 
  }
  return outputArray;
}
```